# Recover database schema from Alembic migrations

Tags: python, alembic, flask-migrate

I recently reinstalled my OS and lost some old data from a local postgre db. But I backed up all the migration files using Alembic. And now I just want to restore the database schema from the migration files, not data. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

It is doable. All migration files have a revision number. Your first migration file has something like:

```
revision = '22a39a2bf2ed'
down_revision = None
```

and your second revision file has something like:

```
revision = '507003430224'
down_revision = '22a39a2bf2ed'
```

As you can see all revision files are linked.

The only thing that you need to do is make your first migration file manually, then run

```
alembic upgrade head
```

Then you need to replace the content of this file with you previous first migration file. Then open your second migration file and replace `downgrade_version` number with this new number.

Now you should be able to run

```
alembic upgrade head
```

again and your database should be upgraded